# Lua C api : How to load lua files defined as modules?

Tags: c, lua

I have the following lua script :

```
module("modoo",package.seeall)
foo=1
bar={12,34}
```

Which works fine using the cli, such as :

```
> dofile "mod_modoo.lua"
> =modoo.foo
1
> =modoo
table: 0x86ce058
```

As far as I understood, it works like a table, but whenever I try loading it as a table, a nil value is pushed onto the stack. Every other table works normally.

I thought using lua_getglobal wouldn't work with modules, but I couldn't find the proper way to load it either ; how should I do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load Lua modules with `require` like `lua.c` does. See http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lua.c.html#dolibrary

```
static int dolibrary (lua_State *L, const char *name) {
  lua_getglobal(L, "require");
  lua_pushstring(L, name);
  return report(L, docall(L, 1, 1));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `module` and `dofile`, it is better practice in Lua 5.1 to simply return a table representing your module when the script is run. All functions and variables should be declared as `local` within the module script so that the returned table provides the only access point and no globals from other modules are trampled. The module should be imported using `require` as follows.

mod_modoo.lua:

```
return { foo = 1,  bar = { 12, 34 } }
```

modoo_test.lua:

```
> local modoo = require "mod_modoo"
```

However, it is often nice to bring the module table (i.e. `modoo`) in as a global without explicitly assigning it. To do so, assign the module table a global reference in addition to returning it from the script. In that case, the module can be used as follows:

mod_modoo.lua:

```
modoo = { foo = 1,  bar = { 12, 34 } }
return modoo
```

modoo_test.lua:

```
> require "mod_modoo"
> print(modoo.foo)
1
```

See the [Lua Module Function Critiqued](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaModuleFunctionCritiqued) article for more information on the matter.

Comment: Why Lua 5.2? It is not released yet.